# How to get Cognito user pool "sub" attribute on iOS

Tags: ios, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I am using a "Cognito User Pool authorizer" (no "AWS_IAM" option, no custom coded authorizer) to call Lambda methods via API Gateway and identify the user logged in on the iOS client.

On Lambda, I use the user id I get from the Cognito User Pool authorizer via `event.requestContext.authorizer.claims.sub` (to store the user id with some DynamoDB items).

I now need to compare this with the id of the logged in user in the iOS client.

I found `[AWSIdentityManager defaultIdentityManager].identityId`, but this (obviously) returns he **IdentityID** (which I can look up in the AWS console in Cognito --> Federated Identities --> Identity Browser), **which is different from the "sub" id** I see in Cognito --> User Pools --> Users and groups

Can I get the "sub" via the AWS iOS SDK?

If I cannot get it, what other id parameter should I use that I can retrieve both on Lambda and the client to identify the current client user/the user making the API request?

Comment: Hi @bob-kinney , are you 100% sure "it has nothing to do with API-Gateway or Lambda"?

Note my last sentence:
"If I cannot get it, what other id parameter should I use that I can retrieve both on Lambda and the client to identify the current client user/the user making the API request?"

I assume if you *are* 100% sure, then you must know the answer, but if you aren't, why did you remove the tags? ;-)

Comment: I may have been too hasty in removing the tags and overlooked your last sentence. Someone from the Cognito team should be able to answer your question regardless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that I have to specifically request the attributes via the user details like this:

```
AWSCognitoIdentityUserPool *pool = [AWSCognitoIdentityUserPool CognitoIdentityUserPoolForKey:AWSCognitoUserPoolsSignInProviderKey];
AWSCognitoIdentityUser *user = [pool currentUser];

NSString *mySub;

[[user getDetails] continueWithBlock:^id _Nullable(AWSTask<AWSCognitoIdentityUserGetDetailsResponse *> * _Nonnull task) {
    if(!task.error){
        AWSCognitoIdentityUserGetDetailsResponse *response = task.result;
        NSArray<AWSCognitoIdentityProviderAttributeType*> *userAttributes = response.userAttributes;
        for (AWSCognitoIdentityProviderAttributeType *attr in self.userAttributes) {
            if ([attr.name isEqualToString:@"sub"]) {
                mySub = attr.value;
            }
        }
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Error fetching Cognito User Attributes: %@", task.error.localizedDescription);
    }
}];
```

Answer (score 2):

Another solution (tested with the AWS JavaScript SDK):

When we authenticate with Cognito, we can retrieve a JWT token:

```
user.authenticateUser(authenticationDetails, {
    onSuccess: (result) => resolve(result.getIdToken().getJwtToken()),
    onFailure: (err) => reject(err)
})
```

It happens that this JWT token is an standard object that can be decoded.

Using [Auth0 JWT decode](https://github.com/auth0/jwt-decode) (npm install jwt-decode), we can decode this token and retrieve all user attributes (e-mail, username, etc.) and the `sub`.

```
var jwtDecode = require('jwt-decode');
var decoded = jwtDecode(token);
console.log(decoded);

// prints sub, email, username, ...
```