# Why are Cognito custom attributes not received in Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cognito

I am using a "Cognito User Pool authorizer" (no "AWS_IAM" option, no custom coded authorizer) to call Lambda methods as HTTPS via API Gateway.

On Lambda, I set a custom user attribute `custom:partnerId` via `adminUpdateUserAttributes` under some circumstances.

I can verify that it has been set correctly via the Cognito User Pools AWS console.

On the iOS client, I can also successfully get all user attributes (including the custom one) as described in my answer at [How to get Cognito user pool "sub" attribute on iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43144135/how-to-get-cognito-user-pool-sub-attribute-on-ios)

The problem is this:

**I do not receive this custom attribute in Lambda** as
`event.requestContext.authorizer.claims['custom:partnerId']` with the next API requests

**until I force the user to sign in explicitly again** (with username/password) on the iOS client.

After this explicit sign in, I then receive the custom attribute included in the `authorizer.claims` parameters as expected.

I don't know whether this is a API Gateway problem (since I assume it is fetching the Cognito user via the HTTP "Authorization" header), a problem with the iOS Cognito SDK, or a problem with Lambda itself.

Comment: API Gateway simply fetches the context variables from Cognito. Since the custom attribute is present when the user signs in again, I think this is related to Cognito. Someone from Cognito should be able to answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cognito User Pool Authorizer in API gateway uses the Id token issued by Cognito. This Id token is valid for 1 hour and automatically gets refreshed by the iOS SDK by calling Cognito refresh API internally. After refresh, the Id Token will have the latest values. Refresh method is not available in high level SDK since it is implicitly called by SDK. But you can use low level SDK and directly call refresh API, this will give you the latest Id Token. (I am a developer from Cognito team and will take this as a feature request to allow ability to refresh from high level SDK.)

Comment: Thanks Vinay! Could you explain which "low level SDK call" I could use for the refresh, until a high level method is available?

Comment: This is the API to call:
 http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito-user-identity-pools/latest/APIReference/API_InitiateAuth.html
This is the low level iOS SDK method:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSiOSSDK/latest/Classes/AWSCognitoIdentityProviderInitiateAuthRequest.html
I can consult our iOS expert in the team, if you have further questions.

Comment: Hi @VinayKushwaha - Can you PLEASE explain your answer a bit more, I am looking to send a custom field on every http proxy call (api gateway), using "$context.authorizer.claims.property" in body mapping.
(https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-mapping-template-reference.html#context-variable-reference)

Will I be able to do that even after refresh token is done ? - thanx in advance